# MySQL Join - Sorting data, grouping data

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables:

**twitterusers table**
[image: Twitterusers Table]

**twittergrowth Table**
[image]

I am trying to do JOIN these 2 tables, get all fields from `twitteruser` and selective fields from `twittergrowth`, then fetch only the last 3 rows from this data.

**Expected Output:**
[image]

**Current Output:**
[image]

I.e the rows are repeating. I want rows unique by ID or usernames, and the last set of timestamps. So it would be the last 3 rows, which has the most recent timestamps.

The code I could type scribble out is :

```
SELECT 
  t1.*,
  t2.new_followers_count,
  t2.new_friends_count,
  t2.new_timestamp     
FROM twitterusers t1 
JOIN twittergrowth t2 on (t1.username=t2.username)
```

Searched quite few pages/sites, but cant really figure out how to do it. I would appreciate any help. :)

Additionally, I would like to get a `LIMIT` parameter added to the final result, so that I can paginate the full result.

Comment: I currently get the first 3 rows using `GROUP BY` wheres as I am looking for the last 3. `new_timestamp` is the variable that changes. Its partially cropped off in the image though.

Comment: If I add an `ORDER BY t2.new_timestamp` the results are arranged, but I cant then use `GROUP BY` to avoid the repetitions. Mysql doesnt allow using `ORDER BY` before `GROUP BY`. So I am basically stuck.

Comment: Why do all users get the same user_id? Do you want to have rows unique by this id and username combined?

Comment: This was dump data entered from a single user_id. Sorry from my part. The user ids will be different.

Comment: And yes, I want the rows to be unique by the user_id and username compared which gives out the latest `new_timestamp` field for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find a maximum `new_timestamp` (latest) within groups of the same `user_id` and `username` in `twittergrowth` table. This is a classic group-wise maximum problem and the subquery `tgmax` does that. Then you need to join back the same table (`tg` this time) to get other columns that aren't in the group by clause of subquery and are not used in aggregate functions (like max()). These columns are `new_followers_count` and `new_friends_count`.

If you tried to put them in the select of subquery mysql would return values from an unspecified row from the same group and not necessarily the same as the one with the latest timestamp. This is explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

Once you get desired output for twittergrowth table the only thing left is to join twitterusers table to get all other columns.

```
SELECT tu.*, tg.new_followers_count, tg.new_friends_count, tg.new_timestamp
FROM twitterusers tu
JOIN twittergrowth tg
  ON tu.user_id = tg.user_id AND tu.username = tg.username
JOIN 
  ( SELECT tgg.user_id, tgg.username, max(tgg.new_timestamp) as latest_timestamp 
    FROM twittergrowth tgg
    GROUP BY tgg.user_id, tgg.username ) tgmax
  ON tg.user_id = tgmax.user_id AND tg.username = tgmax.username
    AND tg.new_timestamp = tgmax.latest_timestamp
```

Note that this query would benefit from a composite index on `(user_id,username,new_timestamp)` in the `twittergrowth` table.

Comment: That code works perfectly. Do you have a minute or 2 to just discuss about the my db schema? I wont make it long. Just want to see if I doing things the right way.

Comment: Schema looks ok to me, you can ask a new question about it if you are not sure.

Comment: The thing I have 2 tables is, One table stores the infos at the time of user adding the username to my system.(That datas never change again). The other table keeps track of updates, a new row for each update. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: If you need a history of changes, yes.

Comment: Yes. I need the history of changes. So this seems to be a good schema to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Also, one more question. Can I provide a user_id to the query above? Like `user_id=1` So that I can have PHP change it on the fly according to the logged in user.

Comment: Yes you can. You can also use limit. How about you just try and see. I can undestand these doubts are too trivial to ask a new question, but please still read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).

Comment: Figured out myself. Tried using LIMIT, ORDER BY and specifying user_id. Works like a charm. Thanks a ton @piotrm

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by to achieve your expected output.

```
GROUP BY id
```

To limit, or split results into pages, you can simply add `LIMIT X,Y` where X is the starting record and Y is the total number of records.

So a query to pull the expected results you want, but only the first 10 would be like so:

```
SELECT 
  t1.*,
  t2.new_followers_count,
  t2.new_friends_count,
  t2.new_timestamp     
FROM twitterusers t1 
JOIN twittergrowth t2 on t1.username=t2.username 
GROUP BY t1.id
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: I just edited my question now. Can you check the expected output once more? I actually wanted the last 3 rows. Currently, I get the first 3 rows.

Comment: Based on what I'm reading this should be what you want. Group By tells MySQL to group the join on a unique column. I.e. if I want unique ids from twitteruser in my results then I'm grouping by that table's id. There are only 3 rows total based on the data you showed?

Comment: Please check the last column `new_timestamp` Half of it is cropped out, but thats a varying value. So I am trying to get the last 3 rows instead of the first 3.

Comment: You can group by more than one value, group by the id then group by the timestamp. I.e. `group by t1.id, timestamp_column` You can use ORDER to sort the data, so getting the last 3 items would be as easy as `order by timestamp_column desc limit 3`

Comment: As I added as a comment to the question, I can use `ORDER BY` but it doesnt allow to use `GROUP BY` after an `ORDER BY`. And I tried grouping by multiple fields. Doesnt give me the expected results.

Comment: You don't seem to understand that what you just said has nothing to do with achieving the expected output you desire... Who cares what order it has to be in? It will still give you the last 3 rows if you put order by first, group by second, and limit 3rd.

Comment: I get the first 3 rows when I use an ORDER BY after GROUP BY. I am looking for the last 3 rows.

Comment: Your question has morphed more than the power rangers :p Nevertheless, if you are grouping by timestamp,id then you will get far more than 3 rows looking at your data.